# Problem: Why is React updating my parent when i am setting state in children? Only happens to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an app that passes event details down to event list and that passes it to a form for editing.

This form is using controlled element so everything gets updated to the state after onChange event.

For some reason, everything is fine (TextField, Switch) when I setting the state back to the form.

However, when I tried it with Array elements, setting the state of an array element will update the props.event_detail all the way back to the original component.

For example

EventList before editing. Click on Edit which will bring up EditEvents:

[image]

Make changes to Summary and array Event Session then click on close

[image]

The summary is not updated, but the Event Session array is

[image]

Code Sand Box 
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-franklin-pslvz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Test Page
https://pslvz.csb.app/?page=admin

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reduce your example down to just the minimum or close to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue you're observing. You have a lot of code to read through here and some things that aren't defined here. Also a live example on Coderpad or JSFiddle would make it easier to debug.

Comment: @CarsonCrane is right - if you actually want people to assist, you have to make it easy for them to help...... help "me" help you.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do, but you should avoid copying the props into the state, per the React Docs

Comment: @CarsonCrane, Thanks for your recommendations, it really looks better with this in code sandbox.

Comment: @MattOestreich, Sorry for the big slab of code, already updated to CodeSandBox for easier reading. Thanks!

Comment: @WebbH, how would you suggest if dont copy the props into state for controlled form elements? Retrieve it again from the database? Would love to hear about your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: I would probably use Redux

Comment: @WebbH I tried Redux but I am still facing the same problem. The thing is, it only affects Array, but not other elements.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit, it was due to this code here.4

Simplified for explanation purpose.

```
const formData, setFormData = React.useState(props.event_detail);

let array_value = formData[name];
array_value[index] = { ...array_value[index], [param]: value };
value = array_value;
setFormData({...formData, [name]=value});
```

Solved it by changing

```
let array_value = Array.from(formData[name);
```

Could be a bug though as it explicitly said it does NOT have allow updating of props from children without calling back to the parents.